# Push Notification does not bring my Android app to foreground

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm wondering if this is normal behaviour of push notifications on an Android device :
When sending a hybrid GCM message with notification (including body, title, icon and sound items) and data payload, my Android device is displaying the message in its notification drawer. That's OK. However, tapping on the message does not bring my app to the foreground and it looks like my app is never receiving the message. 
When I omit the notification payload, so just a data message, then my message is received by my app and I can handle it. In this case it's not displayed in the drawer but I could do it from within my app if I want to.
Moreover, for a hybrid message, when I just remove the icon item from the notification payload, the message is also deliverd to my app and not displayed in the drawer.
Looks very strange to me. It looks like, when a complete notification part is present in the message, Android is handling the message and never delivering it to the app. 
Am I missing something here...?
(App is developed with Xamarin.Android - maybe something missing in the manifest file ?)

Comment: Have you added following lines in your manifest ?

<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>

                <category android:name="your package name"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: Yes I have. However I have one more line in that part, see 'REGISTRATION' below : 
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter><action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" /><action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<category android:name="com.tauris.lisapp" /></intent-filter></receiver>

Comment: try after remove REGISTRATION line

Comment: When searching the internet for examples, I noticed that almost all examples are using data messages to pass the information, not hybrid messages (e.g. they're putting the message text in the data payload, not in the 'body' item of a notification payload). Maybe the reason to do so is related to my question...?

Comment: @Khizar Haya : makes no difference